# Application does not respond after several fileupload

Tags: java, file, tomcat, file-upload

I am doing a jsp which summit a treatment based on uploading a file. My application is in java and runs under Tomcat 8. The problem is that the jsp works fine until the seventh times it is called. A the seventh times the application does not respond anymore.

Some more informations.
On Tomcat 6 there is no problems.
I use file-commons 1.4 and commons-io 2.2.
The garbage collector has no effets.
I can not reproduce the problem in local. (It always works).
I use tomcat 8.5.4. The application is not only used by me so it is difficult to upgrade Tomcat.
I have the error "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, general error".

''' java Dans le jsp.

```
getCurrentData().setUrlStyleReport(" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" ");
```

''' java
// Permet de gérer le multipart.
''' java dans la servlet

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.DiskFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUpload;
if(FileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)){
```

''' java

Comment: there is no differences if i upload big files or small files.

Comment: show us your code.  did you closed all your conncetions, statements and resultset in finally block

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are consuming the db connection pool. This probably means that you are openning connections but you are not closing them. Try to check the limits of number of connections to the db and the process of openning and closing them.